# How to unit test the saving of a collection

Tags: c#, arrays, unit-testing, collections

I am trying to write a unit test for a method that saves multiple records into a database.  The method is passed a collection argument.  The method loops through the collection.  The userid associated with the object is set and the record is updated in the the database.  This is done for every object in the collection.  Any idea on how to create a unit test besides having it write to the database.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have an abstraction over the database CRUD operations (such as a repository pattern)? Ultimately, you want to verify that each record is updated, which can be as simple as faking a repository and verifying all records are submitted to an "Update" method. If you do not have such a replaceable abstraction, then an integration test could certainly be used where you write to a test DB and verify the results, then clean up after yourself.

Comment: Abstract the database logic behind some interface. Mock the interface and see if the required calls are made. If this doesn't helps you post your code.

Comment: Definitely need to have a look at the `Repository Pattern`. It makes persistence a lot easier to test.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, you have an option to abstract the database operations by some interface. If you use ORM, you can implement generic repositories, if you use plain ADO.NET, you can implement something like transaction script.

Another option would be to use SQLite in-memory database. It is not clear what db interface you are using, but SQLite is supported by the majority of database access methods in .NET, including Entity Framework. This would not exactly be a unit test but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

As has been suggested in the comments, you have 2 choices

- Create an abstraction for the actual writing to the database and verify the interactions with that abstraction are as you would expect for your method. This will give you fast unit tests but you will still have to write integration tests for the implementation of your abstraction which actually puts data in the database. To verify the interactions you can either use a mocking library or create an implementation of the interface just for testing with.
- Create an integration test that writes to the database and verify that the data is inserted as you would expect. these tests will be slower, but will give you confidence that the data will actually be placed in the database.

My preference is for the second option, as this tests that the data will actually be persisted correctly, something you are going to have to do eventually, but not everyone likes to do this.

Comment: On your preference, I find a need for both but for different reasons. The method under test here has to loop over multiple records, update a field, and then persist the records to a database. That's logic that can be tested independently of actually *writing* to a database, so that's the unit test. The writing, then, can be a standalone operation that focuses on a single record (such as `repository.Update(item)`), and the concrete Update method should certainly have an integration test to confirm that the record is saved as expected, but that test has nothing to do with the unrelated logic.

Comment: Yeah I appreciate that approach. Recently though I've tended to prefer end to end tests with specflow, and some unit tests to mop up around the edges. They are slower but seen far less brittle, and I dint end up changing all my tests because I decided to restructure the code. YMMV. And I reserve the right to change my mind in the future :-).

Comment: Thanks for all the info.  I should have provided a some additional information.  I am using a Repository Pattern and using JustMock.  After trying a couple of things, I decided to limit the unit test to ensure that the update happened for the same number of items in the collection and that the updated property was set correctly.  This is basically what Anthony Pegram suggested.  

I used Mock.Arrange ...Arg.Matches(to check that the property was updated correctly)...Occurs(3) where 3 represents the number of objects in my collection.